# Code written in Cross-platform library with __ANDROID__ does not execute in Xamarin forms application

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, msbuild, multitargeting

I am using a multi-targeting library in my Xamarin forms application. The library has come code written with `__ANDROID__` conditional compiler symbol. When i run the application on Android, it does not execute the code written with the symbol.

The multi-targeting library project is using MSBuild.Sdk.Extras.

```
<Project Sdk="MSBuild.Sdk.Extras" ToolsVersion="16.0">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;MonoAndroid90</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I also tried it by defining conditional symbol in Xamarin.Android Project Properties  --> Build --> General --> Conditional compilation symbols. But it still does not run that particular code.

```
#if __ANDROID__
        // do some andoid specific work
#endif
```

It should run this code block when running the application on Android.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you have defined `__ANDROID__` symbol in the wrong project. If you define it in e.g. `Project.Android` it's only defined in this project, not the other ones.
There is a possibility to define solution level conditional symbols and you can read about it [here](https://www.vishalon.net/blog/define-conditional-compilation-symbols-at-visual-studio-solution-level)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you forgot to add inside the 'conditional compilation symbols' field inside the build section of the Android project that symbol: ***ANDROID***

I don't know why on iOS when the project is created, the symbol is automatically inserted, while in the Android project it is not inserted.

[image: android build section]
Here the symbols are not preset.

[image: ios build section]

Here the symbols are preset.

You can find more info here under **Conditional Compilation** section:
[microsoft xamarin docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/building-cross-platform-applications/platform-divergence-abstraction-divergent-implementation)